# Search and return value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search

In a nutshell, I have an Excel workbook that updates Exchange Rates, the workbook is driven by dates (fortnightly basis). 
A historical worksheet shows the rates each fortnight – the date is the driver but the issue I am having is that when a rate has not changed I need the formula to search back each fortnight until the last change to the rate was made. I am not sure what formula to use here.

EG:
Fortnight 1 – Set rate; 
Fortnight 2 – No change to Rate; 
Fortnight 3 – No change to Rate; 
Fortnight 4 – No change to Rate; 
Fortnight 5 – change to Rate

Basically thinking in binary terms it would be: 1,0,0,0,1 – so if in fortnight 3 no change then it would pick up fortnight 2, but if this is no change, then goes back to Fortnight 1 (so like a loop until it reaches the last change that was made).

Any help would be much appreciated!

SAMPLE:

14-May-18 = 1; 29-May-18 = 0; 11-Jun-18 = 0; 25-Jun-18 = 1

So on 11 Jun - it would return the value from 14 May as there was no change on 29 May

29 May it would return the value from 14 May as no change to rate on 29 May

If 25 Jun the rate change then it would take the value for that date, else it will go back to 14 May

I hope that clarifies my issue.

Comment: Why not use the idea you described? Do you have any specific constraints?

Comment: Yes constraint is the date, if the rate changes then I need it to return that value, if the rate has not change, I need it to go back until the last change that was made and return that value

Comment: What language are you using? To you need it to be done in Excel?

Comment: Excel, I am looking for a formula or VBA code

Comment: Some sample data and expected output so solution is fit for purpose.

Comment: @Rina Does my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your requirement but let look at the general idea.

Assume those are your data:

[image]

You can run loop who save the index of the last change of rate and then populate it to new column (or override it - up to you):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim last As Integer
last = 0
For i = 2 To 10
    If Cells(i, 2) = 1 Then
        last = i
    End If
    Cells(i, 4) =  Cells(last, 1) //this will save you the date the data were taken from  
    Cells(i, 5) = Cells(last, 3) // this will give you the rate for that date
Next i
```

Hopes that help - if I didn't answer the question feel free to comment